# use of ':' in a jquery function

Tags: jquery-ui, object, jquery-ui-sortable

I recently came across a jquery function which uses jqueryui scrollable.Here is the code:

```
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    change: function(event, ui) {

    var loc = ui.helper.index() < ui.placeholder.index() 
        ? { start: ui.helper.index(), end: ui.placeholder.index() }
        : { start: ui.placeholder.index(), end: ui.helper.index() }
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        });
```

What is the use of " ***:*** " here .Is **loc** an object here with ***start*** and ***end*** as its properties .
If so then can we use ***loc.start*** and ***loc.end*** if needed.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is a ternary operator spread across multiple lines.  Suppose I have this code:

```
var aIsGreater = (a > b) ? true : false;
```

If `a` is greater than `b`, then the first part of the ternary (before the colon `:`) is assigned to `aIsGreater`.  Otherwise the second part of the ternary would be assigned.  Put into the layout of your code:

```
var aIsGreater = (a > b)
  ? true
  : false;
```

In your code, if the return value of `ui.helper.index()` is less than the return value of `ui.placeholder.index()`, then `loc` will be assigned the first object.  otherwise, it will be assigned the second.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer Brad , but in my scenario I am concerned about the " : " inside the  { } braces .Are the ":"used to define the properties of the Object ?